# Explicit Type Conversion in C on a bit level

Tags: c, type-conversion, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

If my c code is:

```
unsigned char Buffer[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0}; 
unsigned long Odometer = 0xff00ff00;

Buffer[3] = Odometer & 0xff;

Odometer = Odometer >> 8;
Buffer[2] = (unsigned char)(Odometer & 0xff);

Odometer = Odometer >> 8;
Buffer[1] = (unsigned char)(Odometer & 0xff);

Odometer = Odometer >> 8;
Buffer[0] = (unsigned char)(Odometer & 0xff);
```

What lies in each index of Buffer? I am not sure how type casting would work on a bit-wise level. Does it transfer the most significant byte or the least significant byte from `Odometer` into each `Buffer` index?

Comment: `Buffer[3]` contains the least significant byte of `Odometer` and `Buffer[0]` the most significant one.

Comment: @ 眠りネロク depending on endianes my friend :)

Comment: This code is endianess-independent so Buffer will contain [0] = MS byte, ... [3] = LS byte, simple as that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To `Buffer[3]` is stored

```
Buffer[3] = Odometer & 0xff;
```

mask between last 8 bits 0xff00ff**00** and 0xff

---

Then you shift `Odometer` 8 bits right so you get 0x00ff00ff

---

To `Buffer[2]` is stored

```
Buffer[2] = Odometer & 0xff;
```

mask between last 8 bits 0x00ff00**ff** and 0xff

---

**And mask between**

```
0xff & 0x00 == 0x00
```

**while**

```
0xff & 0xff == 0xff
```

so **result** is

```
Buffer[3] = 0x00;
Buffer[2] = 0xff;
Buffer[1] = 0x00;
Buffer[0] = 0xff;
```

---

**Bitwise**

```
0 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

so 0x00 & 0xff looks like that

```
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|
-----------------
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0| <-- res
```

while 0xff & 0xff looks like that

```
|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|
|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|
-----------------
|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1| <-- res
```

Comment: You've got `30+` years expirience? Shift is done with `SHR`. [Read here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Shift_and_Rotate). _ and the spaces are always filled with zeros_, so you can take that down vote back :-) @PeterJ

Comment: @PeterJ Remove comment but not downvote after your own mistake? Make placeholders? I dont think person which is programming more than 30 years should do this things.